# How can I solve this error while installing SynapseR?

Tags: r, install.packages

I am trying to install SynapseR on the HPC I am using, so I can run my scripts from there.

```
install.packages("synapser", repos=c("http://staging-ran.synapse.org"))
```

Gives me the error:

```
Installing package into ‘/kyukon/home/gent/456/vsc45640/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.2’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'http://staging-ran.synapse.org/src/contrib/synapser_1.0.57.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-tar' length 154291 bytes (150 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 150 KB

* installing *source* package ‘synapser’ ...
** using staged installation
[1] "*** Using Python Configuration:"
python:         /kyukon/home/gent/456/vsc45640/.virtualenvs/r-reticulate/bin/python
libpython:      /usr/lib64/libpython3.6m.so
pythonhome:     /kyukon/home/gent/456/vsc45640/.virtualenvs/r-reticulate:/kyukon/home/gent/456/vsc45640/.virtualenvs/r-reticulate
version:        3.6.8 (default, Jun 14 2022, 12:54:58)  [GCC 8.5.0 20210514 (Red Hat 8.5.0-10)]
numpy:          /kyukon/home/gent/456/vsc45640/.virtualenvs/r-reticulate/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy
numpy_version:  1.19.5

python versions found: 
 /kyukon/home/gent/456/vsc45640/.virtualenvs/r-reticulate/bin/python
 /kyukon/home/apps/RHEL8/zen3-ampere-ib/software/Python/3.9.6-GCCcore-11.2.0/bin/python3
 /kyukon/home/apps/RHEL8/zen3-ampere-ib/software/Python/3.9.6-GCCcore-11.2.0/bin/python
 /usr/bin/python3
 /usr/bin/python
Using virtual environment '/kyukon/home/gent/456/vsc45640/.virtualenvs/r-reticulate' ...
+ '/kyukon/home/gent/456/vsc45640/.virtualenvs/r-reticulate/bin/python' -m pip install --upgrade --no-user 'requests' 'pandas' 'pysftp' 'jinja2' 'markupsafe'
Requirement already satisfied: requests in /kyukon/home/gent/456/vsc45640/.virtualenvs/r-reticulate/lib/python3.6/site-packages (2.27.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pandas in /kyukon/home/gent/456/vsc45640/.virtualenvs/r-reticulate/lib/python3.6/site-packages (1.1.5)
Requirement already satisfied: pysftp in /kyukon/home/gent/456/vsc45640/.virtualenvs/r-reticulate/lib/python3.6/site-packages (0.2.9)
Requirement already satisfied: jinja2 in /kyukon/home/gent/456/vsc45640/.virtualenvs/r-reticulate/lib/python3.6/site-packages (3.0.3)
Requirement already satisfied: markupsafe in /kyukon/home/gent/456/vsc45640/.virtualenvs/r-reticulate/lib/python3.6/site-packages (2.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: charset-normalizer~=2.0.0 in /kyukon/home/gent/456/vsc45640/.virtualenvs/r-reticulate/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from requests) (2.0.12)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.27,>=1.21.1 in /kyukon/home/gent/456/vsc45640/.virtualenvs/r-reticulate/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from requests) (1.26.15)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in /kyukon/home/gent/456/vsc45640/.virtualenvs/r-reticulate/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from requests) (2023.5.7)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<4,>=2.5 in /kyukon/home/gent/456/vsc45640/.virtualenvs/r-reticulate/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from requests) (3.4)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.15.4 in /kyukon/home/gent/456/vsc45640/.virtualenvs/r-reticulate/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from pandas) (1.19.5)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.7.3 in /kyukon/home/gent/456/vsc45640/.virtualenvs/r-reticulate/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from pandas) (2.8.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2017.2 in /kyukon/home/gent/456/vsc45640/.virtualenvs/r-reticulate/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from pandas) (2023.3)
Requirement already satisfied: paramiko>=1.17 in /kyukon/home/gent/456/vsc45640/.virtualenvs/r-reticulate/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from pysftp) (3.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: bcrypt>=3.2 in /kyukon/home/gent/456/vsc45640/.virtualenvs/r-reticulate/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from paramiko>=1.17->pysftp) (4.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pynacl>=1.5 in /kyukon/home/gent/456/vsc45640/.virtualenvs/r-reticulate/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from paramiko>=1.17->pysftp) (1.5.0)
Requirement already satisfied: cryptography>=3.3 in /kyukon/home/gent/456/vsc45640/.virtualenvs/r-reticulate/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from paramiko>=1.17->pysftp) (40.0.2)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in /kyukon/home/gent/456/vsc45640/.virtualenvs/r-reticulate/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.7.3->pandas) (1.16.0)
Requirement already satisfied: cffi>=1.12 in /kyukon/home/gent/456/vsc45640/.virtualenvs/r-reticulate/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from cryptography>=3.3->paramiko>=1.17->pysftp) (1.15.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pycparser in /kyukon/home/gent/456/vsc45640/.virtualenvs/r-reticulate/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from cffi>=1.12->cryptography>=3.3->paramiko>=1.17->pysftp) (2.21)
Using virtual environment '/kyukon/home/gent/456/vsc45640/.virtualenvs/r-reticulate' ...
+ '/kyukon/home/gent/456/vsc45640/.virtualenvs/r-reticulate/bin/python' -m pip install --upgrade --no-user 'synapseclient==2.7.0'
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement synapseclient==2.7.0 (from versions: 0.1.2, 0.1.4, 0.2.0, 0.2.1, 0.3.0, 0.4.0, 0.4.1, 0.5.0, 0.5.1, 0.5.2, 1.0.1, 1.0.3, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.5.1, 1.6.1, 1.6.2, 1.7.1, 1.7.2, 1.7.3, 1.7.5, 1.8.0, 1.8.1, 1.8.2, 1.9.0, 1.9.1, 1.9.2, 1.9.3, 1.9.4, 2.0.0, 2.1.0, 2.1.1, 2.2.0, 2.2.2, 2.3.0, 2.3.1, 2.4.0, 2.5.0, 2.5.1)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for synapseclient==2.7.0
Error: Error installing package(s): "'synapseclient==2.7.0'"
Execution halted
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘synapser’
* removing ‘/kyukon/home/gent/456/vsc45640/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.2/synapser’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘synapser’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/Rtmpm6z0Np/downloaded_packages’
```

Can someone help me?

I already tried to install the synapseclient on its own, but didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Had this same issue for a while, trying to just install synapser. Here's the workaround I got running. It's a bit more abstraction than installing a simple R library should require, but it works on my machine.

On their github, they have a [dockerfile](https://github.com/Sage-Bionetworks/synapser/blob/master/Dockerfile) that will get you most of the way there. You'll want to copy this file into a local directory then build the image

```
docker build -t synapser .
```

Here, synapser is the name of the docker container. You'll want to create a place to store your data before running, I called this './data' Then you can run an interactive R terminal using this command

```
docker run -v ./data:/data -it synapser
```

And check to make sure synapser is installed

```
library(synapser)
```

Output:

"TERMS OF USE NOTICE:
When using Synapse, ..."

Save your data in /data from inside the container and it will persist after the container is closed.

Phew, it's a lot of work for a 'simple' install.